# $f_n \to 0$ $ a.e.$ and $\lim \int f_n d\mu =0$ but $\sup_n f_n$ is not in $L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

Give an example of a finite measure space $(X,M,\mu)$ and a sequence of functions $f_n:X \to[0, \infty)$ such that $f_n \to 0$ $a.e.$ and $\lim \int f_n d\mu=0$  but $\sup_n f_n$ is not in $L^1$

I have trouble coming up with such an example and prove it. Can someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Try the measure space $X = \mathbb{N}$ with a measure $\mu$ that assigns measure $a_n$ to the integer $n$, where $\sum a_n < \infty$.  Let $f_n$ be a function with $f_n(n) = b_n$ and $f_n(k) = 0$ for $k \ne n$.  Observe that:

- $f_n \to 0$ everywhere
- $\int f_n \,d\mu = a_n b_n$
- $\int \sup_n f_n = \sum_k a_k b_k$.

Now choose $a_n, b_n$ appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Take $X=[0,1]$, $f_n(x) = {1 \over x} \cdot 1_{({1 \over n+1}, {1 \over n}]}(x)$.

Then $f_n(x) \to 0$, $\int f_n = \ln(1+ {1 \over n}) \to 0$, for $x \neq 0$, $\sup_n f_n(x) = {1 \over x}$, hence $\sup_n f_n$ is not integrable.

Answer (score 0):

$X=(0,1)$, with Lebesgue measure, $f_1:=1/x$, $f_n\equiv 0$ for $n\geq 2$.

Comment: what is x here?

Comment: The "variable" $x$ (I meant the function $f_1(x):=1/x$)

Comment: how do you show $1/x$ is not in $L^1$? Thanks

Comment: $\int_0^1 1/x dx = \log 1-\log 0=+\infty$, since $\log x$ is antiderivative of $1/x$.

Comment: The function $1/x$ is Riemann integrable in $(0,1)$ since it is continuous.

Comment: The function is not Riemann integrable in the usually defined sense so far as most texts go, but for nonnegative measurable functions improper riemann integral and lebesgue integral coincide as well.